# Outlook VBA: set folder Archive Policy?

Tags: vba, outlook

Is it possible to get the Archive Policy via VBA in Outlook?  I see there is a property for the retention policy, but I don't see one for the archive policy.  I want to go through all the folders in my Outlook and set them to Archive: Never.